# getAttribute() inside ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In this ajax call, I am calling a servlet in which I set an attribute value.
Now, once I receive the response I am trying get the value of the attribute.
I am struggling for the `getAttribute` value code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#PartNo').keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        varPartCode = $('#PartNo').val();
        $.ajax({  
            type: "Post",  
            url: "submit",  
            data: "PartCode="+varPartCode,  
            success: function(result){ 
                alert($(this).attr("DescAttr"));
            }                
        });
    }   
});

</script>
```

I got the below function from the net. But it is not working. Requesting your help in this.

```
$(this).attr("DescAttr")
```

Below is my code for setting the attribute value in servlet.

```
String varPartDescription = descBean.getPartDescription();
request.setAttribute("DescAttr",varPartDescription);
```

Comment: what version of `jquery` you are using?

Comment: also you can't access  $(this) directly inside ajax success function

Comment: You can use `this` in ajax. Try logging the response to console and read the attribute value

Answer (score 3):

`this` in the success function isn't an HTML element. It does not make sense to pass it as an argument to the jQuery function.

Java attributes have nothing to do with HTML attributes. Setting an attribute on the Java request object isn't going to give any data back to the browser.

You need to put the data in the response and then read it from the argument to the success function in JavaScript that you have named `result`.

For example (and I don't do Java so I just cribbed this from [the first tutorial I found on Google](http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-a-servlet-using-tomcat-server)):

```
res.setContentType("text/plain");
PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();//get the stream to write the data  
pw.println(descBean.getPartDescription());
```

and

```
success: function(result){ 
    alert(result);
}
```

For more complex data, consider outputting JSON instead.

Comment: `*cribbed tutorial*` awesome. i like it as you answered it.